# Find the smallest positive integer $N$ such that $13^N \equiv 1\pmod{2013}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Find the smallest positive integer $N$ such that $13^N \equiv 1\pmod{2013}$.

This is essentially asking for the order of $13^N$ right? I couldn't approach this at all since it's not very easy to compute the powers of $13$. I guess there's another way to approach this?

Comment: $2013=3\times 11\times 61$ so you can solve the problem mod each of those three primes.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify the computations using the *Chinese remainder theorem*:

As $\:2013=3\cdot 11\cdot 61$, we have
$$13^n\equiv 1\mod 2013\iff\begin{cases}13^n\equiv 1 \mod 3,\\
13^n\equiv 1\mod 11, \\13^n\equiv 1 \mod 61.
\end{cases}$$
In other words, you have to find the orders of $13 \bmod 3$ (not very hard…), $11$ and $61$. Its order $\bmod 2013$ will be the l.c.m. of the orders mod. each factor.